# $(\Bbb R, \tau)$ with $\tau$ defined as:
$U\in \tau \iff U=\emptyset \vee 0 \in U$ is not second-countable.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, second-countable

Let $(\Bbb R,\tau)$ be a topological space with $tau$ is defined as:
$$U\in \tau \iff U=\emptyset \vee 0 \in U.$$
Show that $\tau$ is not second-countable.

**Attempt:**
The goal is to show that for any basis $\mathcal{B}$ for a topology $\tau$, then $\mathcal{B}$ is uncountable.
Let $\mathcal{B}$ be any basis for topology $\tau$. By definition, for any $U \in \tau$ and for all $x \in U$, there is $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B \subseteq U$.
But then, how to construct $U$ for which the cardinality of $\mathcal{B}$ and $\Bbb R$ are the same?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$, show that any basis of $\mathbb{R}$ with this topology must contain $\{0,x\}$.

Comment: If it has proved, then since $x \in \Bbb R$ was arbitrary, we have that the basis is uncountable. Like this?

Comment: Does the proof of your hint goes as follows? Let $\mathcal{B}$ be any basis for $\tau$ of $\Bbb R$. By definition, for any $U\in \tau$ and for all $x\in U$, there is $B=\{0,x\} \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$. Thus, any basis for $\tau$ of $\Bbb R$ must contain $\{0,x\}$.

Comment: Thus, since $x \in \Bbb R$  was arbitrary given, we conclude that $|\mathcal{B}|=|\Bbb R|$. Hence, $(\Bbb R,\tau)$ is not second-countable.

Comment: @PitikKepit Yep

Comment: Sorry? What is "Yep"?

Comment: It means yes, you are correct :-)

Comment: Oooh, I see. Pardon Sir :")